# sum of the checked items and stop infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an infinite loop if I select a checkbox

how can i get the sum of the checked items using Angular 8

[her is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular8somedescolumn?embed=1&file=src/app/table-selection-example.ts)

Comment: Explain your problem clearly. From the given description it is not completely understandable - Give some background and context for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite some code has to be simplified in your example. After refactoring TableSelectionExample class, I ended up having the following relevant methods:

```
isAllSelected() {
  const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
  const numRows = this.dataSource.length;
  return numSelected === numRows;
}

toggleSelectionAll(): void {
  this.isAllSelected() ?
    this.selection.clear() :
    this.dataSource.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  this.computeTotal();
}

toggleSelection(row: element): void {
  this.selection.toggle(row);
  this.computeTotal();
}

computeTotal(): void {
  this.totalCal = this.dataSource
    .filter(e => this.selection.isSelected(e))
    .map(e => e.prixElement)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

Consequently I also had to change the template.

Please have a look at the amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-checkbox-selection-total?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.ts).